# Python - to compare sums of even to odd inputs?

Tags: python-3.x

Everyone,

The task is as follows: n digits are to be entered in the console (representing the numbers to follow), the sum of all odd numbers is to be compared to the sum of all even numbers. If the sums are equal, the output should be:

```
Yes
Sum = ...
```

If the sums are not matching, the output should be:

```
No
Diff = ...
```

Why is my below solution now working:

```
n = int(input())

odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0

for i in range(0, n, 2): #this should operate with the even input numbers only, step is 2 so no odd ones
    even_sum = even_sum + int(input())

for i in range(1, n, 2): #this should operate with the odd input numbers only, step is 2 so no even ones
    odd_sum = odd_sum + int(input())

if odd_sum == even_sum:
    print(f'Yes \nSum = {odd_sum}')
else:
    diff = abs(odd_sum) - abs(even_sum)
    print(f'No \nDiff = {diff}')
```

It seems that the separation between the odd and even iterations is now working as intended.. Could you please explain where is the error, the formatting for the range with the provided step of "2" should be fine?

Thanks!

edit: I have tried to solve it with a single for-loop and it seems working this time:

```
n = int(input())

odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0
diff = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    current_num = int(input())
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_sum = even_sum + current_num
    else:
        odd_sum = odd_sum + current_num

if odd_sum == even_sum:
    print(f'Yes \nSum = {odd_sum}')
else:
    diff = abs(odd_sum - even_sum)
    print(f'No \nDiff = {diff}')
```

Comment: Hint: try to append them to a list and print it, you might be surprised...

Comment: You're asking for `input()` on each iteration of each loop. Is this what you mean to do?

Comment: The input should be provided at once e.g. each on a new line in the console: 4 10 50 60 20

Comment: Are you deciding odd or even inputs based on the order in which they are inputed, like If i have input [2,1,4,3,5,9,10], are the odd inputs[1,3,9] and even inputs[2,4,5,10]

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran, yes, exactly - the sum of the odds in order is compared to the sum of the even in order ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a for loop to solve this problem..

Get the list input before hand at one shot as others have suggested.

Getting the elements at odd and even indexes of the list is very easy using list slicing operation. Below example demonstrates that.

```
In [1]: l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [2]: l1[::2]
Out[2]: [1, 3, 5, 7]

In [3]: l1[::-2]
Out[3]: [8, 6, 4, 2]
```

This along with the sum operator will give the odd and even sum you are expecting

```
In [4]: sum(l1[::2])
Out[4]: 16

In [5]: sum(l1[::-2])
Out[5]: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Number of digits you want to enter
n = int(input())
    
odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0
counter = 0
    
while counter < n:
    i = int(input())
    # Test for even
    if i%2 == 0:
        even_sum = even_sum + i
    else:
        odd_sum = odd_sum + i
    
if odd_sum == even_sum:
    print(f'Yes \nSum = {odd_sum}')
else:
    diff = abs(odd_sum) - abs(even_sum)
    print(f'No \nDiff = {diff}')
```

This should work. Also try to use try except blocks to catch proper exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0
while n != 0:
    if n%2 == 0:
        even_sum+=n
    else:
        odd_sum += n
    n=n-1
```

here is a bit shorter code that works unless you're trying to not use while loop

Comment: The task is to be solved solely by using a for-loop, yes. Anyway, thanks much for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

The below code uses just a single for-loop and solves the whole thing - thanks for the worthy contributions!

```
n = int(input())
    
odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0
diff = 0
    
for i in range(0, n):
    current_num = int(input())
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_sum = even_sum + current_num
    else:
        odd_sum = odd_sum + current_num

if odd_sum == even_sum:
    print(f'Yes \nSum = {odd_sum}')
else:
    diff = abs(odd_sum - even_sum)
    print(f'No \nDiff = {diff}')
```